# How to properly format element in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

So I want to use format to manipulate with timepicker in selenium python.

I have following variable:

```py
time = Element('xpath=//li[contains(text(),"{}:{} PM")]')
```

And then I try to use format to located the element:

```py
def select_ten_thirty_time(self):
    self.time_picker.wait_element_to_be_clickable().click()
    self.time.format(10, 30).wait_element_to_be_clickable().click()
```

But I get this error:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: \
Message: Unable to locate element: //li[contains(text(),"{}:{} PM")]
```

EDIT => Added HTML

```
<li class="react-datepicker__time-list-item 
    react-datepicker__time-list-item--selected">10:30 PM</li>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please add HTML?

Comment: Hi @NandanA, I edited the question with HTML. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use f string like this :

```
hour = '10'
sec = '30'
time = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//li[contains(text(),'{hour}:{sec}') and contains(text(),'PM')]")
```

You can have same for `AM` or `PM`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a `xPath` it should work for both `AM` and `PM` times.

```
//li[contains(text(),"10:30 AM") or contains(text(),"10:30 PM")]
```

**Parameterize** the time in `xPath`

```
//li[contains(text(),"+time+" AM") or contains(text(),"+time+" PM")]
```

**Code**:

```
time = '10:30'
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(),"+time+" AM") or contains(text(),"+time+" PM")]")))
```

Comment: Thanks Nandan, what if I want only PM time and how should I properly format the xpath to find the element?

Comment: Can you please see updated solution